# jquery - css "transform:scale" affects '.offset()' of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm Trying To do Validation in jQuery.

It'll produce error after `blur` event occurs by checking whether the given `input` is empty. Based on that, it'll create a `<div class="errdiv">` next to that `input` which will have the specific error. I use `.offset` to get the position of that specific `input` to position `.errdiv` there.

CSS:

```
.inpt {
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    background:#eee;
    color:#444;
    border:2px solid #ddd;
    padding:5px;
    transition: all ease 1s;
    border-radius:5px;
    outline:none;
}
.inpt:focus {
    background:#fff;
    color:#222;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
.err {
    background:pink;
    border:2px solid #f00;
    color:#a00;
}
.errdiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:#a00;
    border:1px solid #a44;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;    
    font-weight:bolder;
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inpt").blur(function(){
        // Check Input for validation.
        $(".errdiv").remove(); //Remove Any Previous Error.
        var vl=$(this).val();
        var vl1=vl.split(" ").join("");
        if(vl==""||vl1==""){
            // Input is Empty Mark It red.
            $(this).addClass("err");
        }
    });
    $(".inpt").focus(function(){
        //Check Whether Input is marked Red or Not (hasClass) err?
        $(".errdiv").remove(); //Remove Any Previous Error.
        if($(this).hasClass("err")){
        // Input is Marked!
        $(this).removeClass("err");
        var tp=$(this).offset().top+12;
        var lf=$(this).offset().left+$(this).width()+12;
         // Add Error Div and appropriate Message.
        $("body").append("<div class='errdiv' style='position:absolute;top:"+tp+"px;left:"+lf+"px;'>*This is Required.</div>");
        $(".errdiv").animate({
            "visibility":"visible",
            "opacity":"1"
        },1000); //Show What is The Error?
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<center>Hello Every One!</center>
<hr>    
<center>
<input class="inpt" placeholder="name" type="text" /><br />
<input class="inpt" placeholder="email" type="text" /><br />
<input class="inpt" placeholder="password" type="password" /><br />
 </center>
 <center>
Just Try Focusing and Bluring the Inputs
</center>
```

And it works fine. You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9hm58/12/).

As you can see it creates error `<div>` and displays it as follows:

[image: "Actual and Expected Output"].

---

### Actual Problem

The Problem occurs when I try to `scale(zoom)` my page for visually impaired peoples and/or for really big screen displays, using:

```
body{
    /*mozilla hack*/
    -moz-transform: scale(1.25,1.25);
    /* Chrome and Safari */
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.25,1.25);
    /*IE */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25,1.25);
    /*Opera*/
    -o-transform:scale(1.25,1.25);
    /*Others*/
    transform:scale(1.25,1.25);
}
```

Then I don't know what happens. But things go terribly wrong. the `.offset()` doesn't seems to work properly. You can see it [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9hm58/13/).

The error `div` now gets positioned as:
[image: Error After Zoom]

---

Can anyone please tell me ***how to position that `.errdiv` correctly even after `scaling` the page***?

What I'm doing wrong?

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome. Hope you all will help me soon. Thanks in advance :).

---

**PS:**

```
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

didn't helped me. and **I don't want to use `<table><td>` or  write `div` previously in `HTML` I want to add it dynamically.**

### Edit For Bounty

The solution I've accepted Is okay for The validation part, But Now I'm trying to implement it with ajax, where the content will be dynamically added to the div, and I've to add `transition:all ease 2.0s` to `body`'s css to make some stuff look amazing. But after adding `trasition` that affects the nature of `transform` which is altered by the solution accepted (transform also gets animated). and it doesn't solve the problem of positioning. So Is there any better way to satisfy the need? Can Anyone please provide a cross browser solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

your problem is that jquery is not returning the correct size of your element (`$(this).width()`).

try using getBoundingClientRect function (refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect)) to get a rectangle object that encloses your element.

you can use it in your function in this way

```
var lf=$(this).offset().left+$(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width+12;
```

try this workaround

http://jsfiddle.net/H5sW9/10/

get current scale in matches[ 1] (scaleX) and matches[ 2] (scaleY)

```
var matrixRegex = /matrix\((-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0,\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0\)/;
var matches =$("body").css('transform').match(matrixRegex);
```

before append store the zoom to 100%

```
$("body").css('transform', 'scale(' + '1' + ')');
```

after you've added the div restore to 125%

```
 $("body").css('transform', 'scale(' + matches[1] + ')');
```

I have used only transform and not -webkit-transition,-moz-transform.... that you should use.

to scale for different factors x and y you should use

```
$("body").css('transform', 'scale(' + '1' +','  +'1' + ')');
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. But it didn't helped :(.

Comment: Why don't? Is the rectangle always at the same position?

Comment: Thanks for spending your time. So here are the fiddles: [With Zoom](http://jsfiddle.net/H5sW9/1/) & [Without Zoom](http://jsfiddle.net/H5sW9/3/).

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks you really Helped me time to time :). Thanks for everything. +1 accepting this answer.

Comment: Nice solution. I'm a bit concerned that this will cause a bit of a flicker. Perhaps it might only appear with a graphic intense page on a mobile device.  Do you think this concern may have any validity?

Answer (score 1):

here is the working solution

**CSS**

```
.inpt:focus {
    background:#fff;
    color:#222;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
.err {
    background:pink;
    border:2px solid #f00;
    color:#a00;
}
.errdiv {
    position:absolute;    
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:#a00;
    border:1px solid #a44;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;    
    font-weight:bolder;
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<center>Hello Every One!</center>
<hr>    
<center>
    <input class="inpt" placeholder="name" type="text" /><br />
    <input class="inpt" placeholder="email" type="text" /><br />
    <input class="inpt" placeholder="password" type="password" /><br />
</center>
<center>
    Just Try Focusing and Bluring the Inputs
</center>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inpt").blur(function() {
        // Check Input for validation.
        $(".errdiv").remove(); //Remove Any Previous Error.
        var vl = $(this).val();
        var vl1 = vl.split(" ").join("");
        if (vl == "" || vl1 == "") {
            // Input is Empty Mark It red.
            $(this).addClass("err");
        }
    });
    $(".inpt").focus(function() {
        //Check Whether Input is marked Red or Not (hasClass) err?
        // $(".errdiv").remove(); //Remove Any Previous Error.
        if ($(this).hasClass("err")) {
            // Input is Marked!
            $(this).removeClass("err");
//            var tp=$(this).offset().top+12;// not needed 
//            var lf=$(this).offset().left+$(this).width()+12;// not needed
//             // Add Error Div and appropriate Message.
            $('<div class="errdiv">*This is Required.</div>').insertAfter(this);

            $(".errdiv").animate({
                "visibility": "visible",
                "opacity": "1"
            }, 1000); //Show What is The Error?
        }
    });
});
```

A bit of modification that is all

Remove top and left property from your .errdiv class and append the div dynamically after the element

Comment: Nice Solution mate. +1. But this is just a simple example to make people understand the problem, In my real page, There are several elements inside one another of DOM tree, so I can't use this approach there. That's why I need `.top` and `.left`. Thanks btw for spending your time.

Comment: i understand this is just sample and your application must be more complex. But have you tried this solution in your application? I tested this code in a little bit complex scenario and it is working for me, So if you haven't then give it a try.

Comment: And add `position:relative` to element after which you want to append the div element

Answer (score 0):

I met a pretty similar issue but the problem was that the JS was not fully loaded when I tried to call .offset.

Adding a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Do the offset thing here
}
```

Solved my problem.

I hope this solution may help some people passing by.